# How to create crashlytics binding for Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, crashlytics

I've downloaded Crashlytics app that integrates Crashlytics.framework into XCode project, and it works great for XCode. But as far as I know, to build Xamarin.iOS binding I need static library, and I can't find it neither in framework nor in Crashlytics.app contents. There is only "run" executable and header. I don't know how to use it under Xamarin.iOS. Btw, [AndrewReed on Xamarin forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6944/crashlytics-and-crittercism-crashing) managed to build dll somehow, so it's possible.

So, **how to create crashlytics binding for Xamarin?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AndrewReed answered this question on Xamarin forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/25441/#Comment_25441):

> As with quite a few sdk's, sometimes they bundle a folder instead of the static lib,which essentially is the static library. There will be a sizeable file that maybe doesnt have an extension(this is your .a file) so you can rename that to be .a and then include that in a xamarin bindings project. Run the sharpie marker on the header file in the folder which will generate your necessary files. Watch out for one gotcha, delegate is a reserved word in c#, so you may need to go around and change this by adding an @ symbol(to the name) to allow you to use the reserved word.
> So what I actually did was, created a project in xcode and ran the crashlytics programme, this then added the crashlytics framework to the project. In finder locate that and you will have a structure like so: - run - /Versions --/A ---Crashlytics ---/Headers ----Crashlytics.h
>
> So the /A folder is essentially your static lib, use this and create your binding from that, or in this particular case, just download it from the mono bindings || [my repo](https://github.com/Reedyuk/Xamarin-Bindings).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an officially supported crash reporting plugin, [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com) just released one (Full disclosure: I'm one of the co-founders).  You can download the bindings from the Xamarin store here: http://components.xamarin.com/view/crittercism

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Xamarin seems to have it build in.
Here are the steps that I followed

1.) In the Xamarin Studio , go to the main app, and add the Crashlytics API key in the Build -> Crash reporting section. Build and run that app. The evidence suggests that is enough to get data sent to Crashlytics. I saw that it knew about older versions of the app I had built and ran weeks ago with the API key already in.

2.) Go to Xcode and create a new project with the same name as the Xamarin project, com.{company}.{appname}. (You probably need to have that profile downloaded.) I did it in Swift by the way with no issues.

3.) Go to crashlytics.com com and go to settings -> Apps (or https://www.crashlytics.com/onboard)

4.) You will get an app to download and run. The app walks through the steps of adding

A.) A build phase run script

B.) Code to the application main Crashlytics.startWithAPIKey(“nnnn”)

5.) Run your Xcode version of the app

The Crashlytics web page popped up immediately.