# Crittercism make the iOS app crash built by xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, crittercism

I want to use Crittercism in iOS app built by xamarin, but the app will crash after enable it. I have found the solution at [How to create crashlytics binding for Xamarin.iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530198/how-to-create-crashlytics-binding-for-xamarin-ios) and add the codes suggested but the app still crash. The version of Crittercism is 4.3.0 and xamarin is 4.2.2. Does anyone successfully make it working under that environment?

Thanks!

Comment: This is probably the problem (and solution): http://stackoverflow.com/q/14499334/183422

Answer (score 2):

This is Rob, one of the co-founders of [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com).  We actually just released an officially supported Xamarin Plugin!  It handles interactions with the Mono runtime pretty nicely - for example, we purposely don't override fatal signals like SIGSEGVs which the Mono runtime should handle and send us better stacktraces.  You can download it here:

http://components.xamarin.com/view/crittercism