# Using Crashlytics in MonoTouch

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios

I am trying to use Crashlytics iOS library in my MonoTouch app. I have created a MonoTouch Binding project and created ApiDefinition.cs file using Object Sharpie tool.
Below is my ApiDefinition.cs

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

 namespace Crashlytics {

[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
public partial interface Crashlytics {

    [Export ("apiKey", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    string ApiKey { get; }

    [Export ("version", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    string Version { get; }

    [Export ("debugMode")]
    bool DebugMode { get; set; }

    [Export ("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Assign)]
    NSObject Delegate { get; set; }

    [Static, Export ("startWithAPIKey:")]
    Crashlytics StartWithAPIKey (string apiKey);

    [Static, Export ("startWithAPIKey:afterDelay:")]
    Crashlytics StartWithAPIKey (string apiKey, double delay);

    [Static, Export ("startWithAPIKey:delegate:")]
    Crashlytics StartWithAPIKey (string apiKey, NSObject @delegate);

    [Static, Export ("startWithAPIKey:delegate:afterDelay:")]
    Crashlytics StartWithAPIKey (string apiKey, NSObject @delegate, double delay);


    [Static, Export ("sharedInstance")]
    Crashlytics SharedInstance { get; }

    [Export ("crash")]
    void Crash ();

    [Export ("userIdentifier")]
    string UserIdentifier { set; }

    [Export ("userName")]
    string UserName { set; }

    [Export ("userEmail")]
    string UserEmail { set; }

    [Export ("setObjectValue:forKey:")]
    void SetObjectValue (NSObject value, string key);

    [Export ("setIntValue:forKey:")]
    void SetIntValue (int value, string key);

    [Export ("setBoolValue:forKey:")]
    void SetBoolValue (bool value, string key);

    [Export ("setFloatValue:forKey:")]
    void SetFloatValue (float value, string key);
    /*
    [Static, Export ("setObjectValue:forKey:")]
    void SetObjectValue (NSObject value, string key);

    [Static, Export ("setIntValue:forKey:")]
    void SetIntValue (int value, string key);

    [Static, Export ("setBoolValue:forKey:")]
    void SetBoolValue (bool value, string key);

    [Static, Export ("setFloatValue:forKey:")]
    void SetFloatValue (float value, string key);
    */
}

[Model, BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
public partial interface CLSCrashReport {

    [Export ("identifier")]
    string Identifier { get; }

    [Export ("customKeys")]
    NSDictionary CustomKeys { get; }

    [Export ("bundleVersion")]
    string BundleVersion { get; }

    [Export ("bundleShortVersionString")]
    string BundleShortVersionString { get; }

    [Export ("crashedOnDate")]
    NSDate CrashedOnDate { get; }

    [Export ("OSVersion")]
    string OSVersion { get; }

    [Export ("OSBuildVersion")]
    string OSBuildVersion { get; }
}

[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
[Model]
public partial interface CrashlyticsDelegate {

    [Export ("crashlytics:crashlyticsDidDetectCrashDuringPreviousExecution:")]
    void  CrashlyticsDidDetectCrashDuringPreviousExecution(Crashlytics crashlytics);

    [Export ("crashlytics:didDetectCrashDuringPreviousExecution:")]
    void DidDetectCrashDuringPreviousExecution (Crashlytics crashlytics, CLSCrashReport crash);
}
}
```

When i compile project i am getting error at NSObject delegate. So i have added @, recommendation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530198/how-to-create-crashlytics-binding-for-xamarin-ios)

```
 [Static, Export ("startWithAPIKey:delegate:")]
 Crashlytics StartWithAPIKey (string apiKey, NSObject @delegate);

 [Static, Export ("startWithAPIKey:delegate:afterDelay:")]
 Crashlytics StartWithAPIKey (string apiKey, NSObject @delegate, double delay);
```

Now i compile again, i get error at Crashlytics.g.cs file Unexpected Symbol delegate

```
     [Export ("startWithAPIKey:delegate:")]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public static Crashlytics StartWithAPIKey (string apiKey, NSObject delegate)
    {
        if (apiKey == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException ("apiKey");
        if (delegate == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException ("delegate");
        var nsapiKey = NSString.CreateNative (apiKey);

        Crashlytics ret;
        ret =  Runtime.GetNSObject<Crashlytics> (MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr (class_ptr, selStartWithAPIKeyDelegate_Handle, nsapiKey, delegate.Handle));
        NSString.ReleaseNative (nsapiKey);

        return ret;
    }
```

how to add delegate in the file created using Object Sharpie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not using `delegate` as a parameter name in your binding code, since it's a reserved word in C# (and the generator doesn't work properly with reserved words).